# ArcGIS Pro - unique values symbology not displaying for raster data

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, symbology, unique-value

I am hoping someone may be able to help. I have a rather large raster (GeoTIFF) which I am trying to display as 'unique values' in ArcGIS Pro. However, the symbology pane is not showing any values and I am unable to set the symbology.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's an integer raster? There is a limit on how many unique values ArcGIS can handle.

Comment: Have you clicked the "Add all values" button?